# Restoring database on Heroku from local dump using Cloud App

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, database-restore

I am trying to restore a database from my development environment to the production.

I have followed the steps in 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

I've created a dump locally and have uploaded it using CloudApp. Then I ran this command:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL 'http://cl.ly/<some_id>/myapp.dump'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL (DATABASE_URL) <---restore--- myapp.dump

! WARNING: Destructive Action
! This command will affect the app: myapp
! To proceed, type "myapp" or re-run this command with --confirm myapp

> myapp

Retrieving... done

! An error occurred and your restore did not finish.
```

And if I take a look at the logs, it ends with this:

```
2012-12-02T17:30:42+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start
2012-12-02T17:30:42+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: 0B 
2012-12-02T17:30:42+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 
2012-12-02T17:30:42+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: 0.0bytes
2012-12-02T17:30:42+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done
2012-12-02T17:30:42+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid path
```

I have tested the url and it looks okay, I have searched for similar issues on the web, but found no answer.

I have also tried to run `heroku update` but it was already up-to-date

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

I've also send a support ticket to them, but until they answer, I'd also like to hear if any of you stumbled upon something similar.

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with the URL being shortened. Have you tried uploading the file elsewhere and using a full URL, S3 for instance.

Comment: What do you mean shortened? It's not redirecting if you are wondering about that. It's a direct download link (raw file),  just like S3 would be.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I saw the cl.ly and assumed it was a shortened URL. My bad. As a sanity check anyway, I'd be tempted to try uploading the dump to another source, just to double check there isn't a problem there.

Comment: Ok, this worked with Dropbox... conclusion: sanity - none!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad that worked for you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I too could not get this to work with Cloud App, but was successful using Dropbox.